# Where do I get a pickaxe?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have now thus far wandered the cold mountains of Skyrim for many hours, and I have seen many "ore" deposits that seem "mine-able".  When I attempt to interact with these deposits I get a message that says something to the effect of "you need a [pickaxe](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pickaxe#Pickaxe) to mine that".  I'll check the exact message text next time I'm playing.  I've been to several towns, and I haven't seen a pickaxe for sale anywhere.  Am I missing something?  Where do I get what I need to mine ore?

Comment: REAL miners won't settle for less than scaling the Throat of the World to get the [Notched Pickaxe.](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Notched_Pickaxe)

Comment: @desaiw Generally I don't think so - but then, it appears a comment of mine was deleted or never got posted as well.  Odd...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Picks turn up commonly in and around mines - look for the crossed hammer icon on the maps (shown here):

[How do I find an ore mine?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35372/how-do-i-find-an-ore-mine)

You'll also see them in some of the shops in the villages.

Answer (score 6):

In case you are fed up of searching for a pickaxe and really need one immediately (as sometimes happens with me when I'm searching for some particular item), you can just spawn one in your inventory using a cheat code. Although it's cheating I feel it is okay because after all it's just an ordinary pickaxe and you're saving yourself the grind of searching for it.

Here's what to do on the pc version:

1. Press the <kbd>`</kbd> key (tilde key) to bring up the console
2. Type `player.additem E3C16 1` and enter.

Here E3C16 is the code for a pickaxe. Happy mining!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to buy one. Almost every [mine](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mines) will have a [pickaxe](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Pickaxe) lying around that you can use.

If not,check various barrels and sacks,also they are often found on enemies you kill in mines.